# javascript's String replace method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, replace

I have the following sentence:

`One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest`

I'd like to remove any instance of `"the"` and `"'"` from the sentence so the output is the following:

**Expected output:**

`one flew over cuckoos nest`

I use the following code:

```
var guess = "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest";
guess = guess.toLowerCase().replace("'", "").replace("the", "");
```

**Actual Output:**

`one flew over  cuckoos nest`

The problem is that there's a space appearing after `"over"` because I'm only removing `"the"` from that particular sentence and not the space afterwards.

I know I can fix this by using `replace("the ", "");` but I would like a better way to achieve the result.

Would there be a regular expression I can use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem you will face is that `replace` only replaces the *first* match. In order to replace all of them, you need to use a regex with the `g`lobal modifier.

```
guess = guess.toLowerCase().replace(/the|'/g,'').replace(/  +/g,' ');
```

The second `replace` contains two spaces followed by a `+`. This will fix any "broken" spaces caused by the words being removed. Also, in the first one an alternation is used to get both the `the` words and apostrophes in one shot.

Comment: This seems to do the trick for the removal of `"the"`, but it won't work with something like: `"The King's Speech"` => `"kings speech"`.

Answer (score 2):

personally I would do

```
var guess = "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest";
guess = guess.toLowerCase().replace("'", "").replace(" the", "").replace("the ", "");
```

I'm sure there's some regEx for this, but seems overkill

I'm not a regEx expert, so I can't offer you a solution in regEx

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a big regex expert myself. I think I'll just use the two replaces in the end.

Comment: Are these all titles? It may be safe to assume none of the strings end in `" the"` so you could just go with replacing `"the "`

Comment: Yeah, they're all titles. I could probably just get away with your answer actually. I'll run some tests.